# How to control an AlertDialog resize after the keyboard appears

Tags: flutter

I built an `AlertDialog` that resizes (shrinks) when the keyboard appears to edit a `TextField`. I like this behaviour, but the problem is that for some screen sizes it causes a bottom overflow of the `Dialog`.

Is there a way to control the size of the `AlertDialog` after being shrunk by the appearance of the keyboard?

I tried wrapping the whole thing with a SingleChildScrollView but then the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` does not work as before in the `Column`.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

Use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` as false

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
   //...
)
```

This useful when there is an onscreen keyboard displayed above the
scaffold, the body can be resized to avoid overlapping the keyboard.

Comment: But I do want the resizing. I just need to control the height of the widget after resizing so that I dont get overflown content

Comment: Could you add screenshot?

Comment: I just added two screenshots